# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.harry.foodapp.Model.AdminOrders

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a shopping App and I want to add a 'Orders' tab where the Users can see their own orders that is pending at the moment. I already have made  'Orders' tab where the Admin can see all user orders, in the Admin Panel. I used the same block of codes for the current user's Orders list activity too. But it shows every all the orders of every user. I don't know how to fix that. I have a model class to get the Current online user. I tried that also but didn't work.

Here's what I tried...

```
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    final DatabaseReference ordersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orders");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdminOrders> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdminOrders>()
                    .setQuery(ordersRef
                            .child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())
                            , AdminOrders.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminOrders, AdminOrdersViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdminOrders, AdminOrdersViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final AdminOrdersViewHolder holder, final int position, final @NonNull AdminOrders model)
                {
                    holder.userName.setText("Name : "+ model.getName());
                    holder.userPhoneNumber.setText("Phone Number : "+ model.getPhone());
                    holder.userTotalPrice.setText("Total : Rs."+ model.getTotalAmount());
                    holder.userDateTime.setText("Order Time : "+ model.getDate() + model.getTime());
                    holder.userShippingAddress.setText("Address : "+ model.getAddress() + "," + model.getCity());
                    holder.showOrdersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            String uID = getRef(position).getKey();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(UserViewOrdersActivity.this, AdminUserProductsActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("uid", uID);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    if(model.getFast_delivery()){
                        holder.txtFastDel.setText("Fast Delivery : Yes");
                    }else{
                        holder.txtFastDel.setText("Fast Delivery : No");
                    }
                }
```

**AdminOrders**

```
public class AdminOrders
{
    String name;
    String phone;
    String address;
    String state;
    String time;
    String totalAmount;
    String city;
    String date;
    String postal_code;
    Boolean fast_delivery;

    public AdminOrders()
    {
    }

    public AdminOrders(String name, String phone, String address, String state, String time, String totalAmount, String city, String date, String postal_code, Boolean fast_delivery) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.state = state;
        this.time = time;
        this.totalAmount = totalAmount;
        this.city = city;
        this.date = date;
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
        this.fast_delivery = fast_delivery;
    }
```

**AdminOrdersViewHolder**

```
public static class AdminOrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView userName, userPhoneNumber, userTotalPrice, userDateTime, userShippingAddress, txtFastDel;
        public Button showOrdersBtn, viewLocationBtn;
        public Switch fast_delivery;
        public AdminOrdersViewHolder (View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderUserName);
            userPhoneNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderPhoneNumber);
            userTotalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderTotalPrice);
            userDateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderAddressCity);
            userShippingAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderDateTime);
            showOrdersBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showAllProductsBtn);
            viewLocationBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewLocationBtn);
            txtFastDel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFastDel);
            fast_delivery = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fast_delivery);
        }
    }
```

[image: database]

And here's the error I'm getting

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.harry.foodapp.Model.AdminOrders
```

Comment: Please post your model and similar entity between user and your database fields (something like his name or uid)?

Comment: @Ashish Done mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
.setQuery(ordersRef
.child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername()), AdminOrders.class)
```

into this:

```
.setQuery(ordersRef, AdminOrders.class)
```

When you add `child(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())`, you are retrieving the attributes as `String`. So you need to map the json to the model class. Example:

```
 {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars": {
    "car1":"Ford",
    "car2":"BMW",
    "car3":"Fiat"
  }
 }
```

Here `cars` is an object that contains the attributes `car1`, `car2` and `car3`. In your case `admin` is the object and inside of it there is the attributes.

Comment: Thanks sir! But When I set it as '.setQuery(ordersRef, AdminOrders.class)', it retrieves all the orders including other users' orders...

Comment: yes it will retrieve for other users' also, this is a recycler view, thats the whole point of using recyclerview, if u want only for one user then dont use recyclerview just retrieve them and do setText

Comment: Can I still retrieve the information to the RecyclerView and filter it by the User's name?

Comment: yes u can do `ordersRef.orderByKey().equalto(Prevelant.currentOnlineUser.getUsername())`